# Background image doesn't fill out the whole height

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to get the image (176x220 pixels) to fill the screen of a flip phone with Opera Mini web browser.
The bottom of the blue image is clipped off or not showing. Can someone show me why that is and how to fix it? Thanks.

[mobile phone display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgE36.jpg)

```
.vb {
    background-image: url('img/176x220.png');
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size: cover;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body class="vb">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no clue what browser that phone is using, but I would imagine it is a version prior to the ones listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It appears that Opera Mini (Mobile) doesn't support it then.